# Фрагмент и вложенные классы "java.lang.IllegalStateException: Activity has been destroyed"

Tags: android, java

Помогите решить проблему.
Пытаюсь механизм создания фрагментов, оформить в виде отдельного класса.
но попытка это сделать приводит к ошибке "java.lang.IllegalStateException: Activity has been destroyed"

Вот мой код:

//Основной Activity

```
 public class MainActivity extends SherlockActivity{
     ..............

  myFragment f =new myFragment();
  f.run();

    ...............

}
```

//Класс по созданию фрагмента

```
public class myFragment extends Activity{

  public void run(){
  bar = new BarFragment();
  fTrans = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
  fTrans.add(R.id.fragmentContainer, bar);
  fTrans.commit(); 
  }
}
```

Comment: Невозможно ничего сказать. Нужен полный текст из файла с Activity

Comment: от меня скрывается смысл наследования myFragment  от Activity, что Вы хотите сделать ?

Comment: Фрагменты так не создаются. Нужно делать через FragmentManager, но именно в Activity.

Comment: Мне нужно сделать код более понятным, поэтому я и хочу разнести все по отдельным классам

Comment: предлагаю вам изучить какие-то основы Андроида прежде чем писать на нем программы.    
Фрагменты не могут жить без Активити, которое в свою очередь недостаточно просто создать как объект. Оно должно быть запущено.

Answer (score 1):

Вот правильный ответ на поставленный вопрос.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15207305/getting-the-error-java-lang-illegalstateexception-activity-has-been-destroyed

ДОБАВИЛ:
В каждом дочернем фрагменте требуется прописать процедуру отсоединения фрагмета:

```
@Override
public void onDetach() {
    super.onDetach();

    try {
        Field childFragmentManager = Fragment.class.getDeclaredField("mChildFragmentManager");
        childFragmentManager.setAccessible(true);
        childFragmentManager.set(this, null);

    } catch (NoSuchFieldException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
}
```

Comment: Хотя по ссылке можно найти ответ на вопрос, лучше указать выдержку ответа здесь, а ссылку приводить в качестве источника. Ответы-ссылки могут стать недействительными в случае изменения страницы, на которую дана ссылка.

Comment: @fori1ton, спасибо, вы правы.